# Using Forge, how can I output the contract content in the output metadata?

Tags: foundry, forge, build-from-source

I want to get the source code sent to the compiler when using `forge build`.

The output files currently have only the urls and not the content:

```
"sources": {
      "contracts/MyContract.sol": {
        "keccak256": "0x9700643a548854f5f1e7edff5742b4e69b62dc90287cd927c742111000000000",
        "urls": [
          "bzz-raw://3b1cc66bdbdf506de0cfe6859369ca595fe5468e87fb69dbfb0a566d00000000",
          "dweb:/ipfs/QmcWfxahnMFoj8nTGZRno6LYvwK4LoXL9US35Y00000000"
        ],
        "license": "MIT"
      },
```

Are there any flags I can add so that the output contains the content, e.g.:

```
"sources": {
      "contracts/MyContract.sol": {
        "content": ""// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT\r\n..."
      },
```